# How do I Export Java Code in AnyLogic (NOT Documentation function tables)?

Tags: java

I know AnyLogic has a documentation function, but I would like to review the complete Java code. How do I export just the raw Java code?

Answer (score 1):

You can open your agents with a java editor and copy paste that

:
[image: java editor]